# how to group this array

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I have the following array and I want to group all the users of same company together. Currently every user is shows up with a company id and some times there are 2 or more users under one compay. So I kinda want to revert it and show the users under company not company under users. How'd I go about doing that

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [company_id] => 20
                    [type] => 
                )


        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                    [company_id] => 21
                    [type] => 
                )


        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 7
                    [company_id] => 22
                    [type] => 
                )


        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 14
                    [company_id] => 21
                    [type] => 
                )


        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 15
                    [company_id] => 22
                    [type] => 
                )



        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 16
                    [company_id] => 21
                    [type] => 
                )


                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the example I suppose that your relations are as follows:

"User belongsTo Company" and "Company hasMany User"

@tigrang is right, if you do a find on Company, you will get the users Grouped by Company:

```
$this->Company->find('all', array('conditions' => array('id' => $companyId)));
```

If your Company Model has many other relations and you need only the Users you can use the ContainableBehaviour. Firstly add it in the Company model:

```
public $actsAs = array('Containable);
```

Then in the find() call:

```
$this->Company->find('all', array('conditions' => array('id' => $companyId), 'contain' => array('User')));
```

The 'contain' key accepts an array of Model names or a string for a single Model. It will adjust the model bindings on the fly, leaving you only with the Company and User models' data (if used as in the example above).

And a little thing I missed. You can also use the 'group' key in a find over the User model:

```
$this->User->find('all', array('group' => 'company_id'));
```

Try both approaches and see what you come up with.

Answer (score -1):

Do a find on the Company model instead using either recursive or ContainableBehavior.

Comment: Although your answer is correct, it does not seem to fully answer the question, as there is no exact example.

Comment: @Borislav Sabev I think it answers the question: "How'd I go about doing that." Where did it ask for an example? All Autolycus said is how you would go about doing that.